# Java.IO.ISerializable Xamarin

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to pass object in Android using Iserializable, but it return me "Unable to activate instance of type from native handle" exception.

Below are my codes.

[FBUserParcel.cs]

```
using System;
using Android.OS;
using PlayCardLeh.Helpers;

    namespace PlayCardLeh.Android
    {
        public class FBUserParcel:Java.Lang.Object, Java.IO.ISerializable
        {
                Xamarin.Facebook.Model.IGraphUser fbUser;
                public FBUserParcel (Xamarin.Facebook.Model.IGraphUser user)
                {
                    fbUser = user;

                }
            }
    }
```

[MainActivity.cs]

```
private async Task FindFBUser(Xamarin.Facebook.Model.IGraphUser user) {
    if (user != null) {
        Console.WriteLine ("GOT USER: " + user.Name);
        try {
            var t = await User.FindUserWithFBID (user);
        }
        catch(NotFound NotFound) {

            RunOnUiThread (() => {
                Intent i = new Intent (this,typeof (RegisterActivity));
                FBUserParcel u = new FBUserParcel(user);
                StartActivity (i);
            });

        }

    }

    else
        Console.WriteLine ("Failed to get 'me'!");
}
```

RegisterActivity.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);
    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Register);

    if (Intent.HasExtra ("fbUser")) {
        var u = Intent.Extras;
        u.GetSerializable ("fbUser");

    }
}
```

The exception happen at "u.GetSerializable ("fbUser");". Sorry I'm kinda new to Xamarin, anyone have exprience with using Iserializable? What did I missed out in "FBUserParcel.cs" ??

Thanks Mug4n for sharing a link that discuss about the same issue. 
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/451/communicate-with-iserializable

Comment: You have to implement the serialization yourself. Take a look at this post: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/451/communicate-with-iserializable

Comment: Thanks mug4n for the link. I guess it's not the same as Java for android where I can just implement serializable and it will just work in another activity.

Comment: Maybe you can come back later and post a solution to this problem.

Comment: Remember that if you want a variable to have a value among fragments or activities a pretty good way to do is by using The Application class as it is described here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/811464/Introduction-to-Xamarin-Android and access your public variables like this:
MyApplication application = (MyApplication)GetContext();
String username = application.GetCurrentUser();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you could solve it easily by just serializing `Xamarin.Facebook.Model.IGraphUser` with any serializer which produces `string` or `byte[]`.
For example if you use [Newtonsoft's Json.NET](https://components.xamarin.com/view/json.net/) component your code would look something like that:

```
Xamarin.Facebook.Model.IGraphUser fbUser;
var fbUserSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (fbUser);
intent.PutExtra ("fbUser");
```

And to deserialize:

```
if (Intent.HasExtra ("fbUser")) {
    var fbUserSerialized = Intent.GetStringExtra ("fbUser");
    var fbUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Xamarin.Facebook.Model.IGraphUser>(fbUserSerialized);
}
```